# How can I have the right ctrl key behave as the left ctrl key?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I would like to have the left and right ctrl keys to behave the same.
I already have the left key working as it should, in all the shortcuts, etc., but the right one seems to be completely ineffective.
I have looked in the keyboard layout options, but with no results.

I am on Linux Mint 20.2, with Mate desktop environment.

--addendum--

The result of `xev` is as follows:

```
KeyPress event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
root 0x7ac, subw 0x5200002, time 416256, (49,43), root:(2600,505),
state 0x10, keycode 105 (keysym 0xff20, Multi_key), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: True

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
root 0x7ac, subw 0x5200002, time 416464, (49,43), root:(2600,505),
state 0x10, keycode 105 (keysym 0xff20, Multi_key), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

The output of `xmodmap` is as follows:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Comment: Can you see `Control_L` and `Control_R` respectively when you press left and right controls after running `xev` in the terminal?

Comment: I see "Control_L" for the left ctrl, but for the right ctrl I receive a "Multi_key".

Comment: what's the output of your `xmodmap`?

Comment: @Andra
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)

Comment: ok, try, first, `xmodmap -e "keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R"`, then `xmodmap -e "add control = Control_R"`. If it doesn't work, then again it would be worth to see the output of `xmodmap` **after** these commands, and `xev` for the right control.

Comment: @Andra it worked! thank you!
Post the comment as an answer, and I will approve it :)

Comment: Glad to hear it! By the way, you can improve your question if you add `xev` output showing this Multi_key and the output of `xmodmap` (like in the comment on Jan 6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a more stable and final solution!
The behavior I want (both ctrl keys, left and right, having the same behavior) is indeed the default.

My problem was that a keyboard setting was changing this default.

I just found this setting, I have de-selected it, and the default (wanted) behavior is obtained!

The setting is reached as follows:

Keyboard preferences -> Layouts -> Options -> Position of Compose key -> Right Ctrl.

Below I report the screenshots:

[image: first window of the Keyboard Preferences]

[image: second window for the layout options]

Answer (score 1):

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 105 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L"
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work, sorry... :(

Comment: Important note for people who might want to do this on Ubuntu 20+: The default windowing system used is Wayland, in which this won't work. This solution is for X.Org windowing system. You can select the X.Org windowing system (on which this solution should work) in the login screen where you enter your password (click the small gear icon at the bottom right of the screen and select - Ubuntu on X.Org if the two options are Ubuntu and Ubuntu on X.Org - Ubuntu on Wayland if the two options are Ubuntu and Ubuntu on Wayland

Answer (score 1):

As you confirm in comments, the following two `xmodmap` commands do the trick:
`xmodmap -e "keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R"`
`xmodmap -e "add control = Control_R"`

It will not stay after reboot, so you need to save only the text in quotes in ~/.Xmodmap file and make it executed at startup.

Comment: could you please help with the "after restart" part, please? I have created the ~/.Xmodmap file, I have copied the two lines: keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R add control = Control_R then I have followed all the suggestions in this post:
 https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=294096
but with no success :(

Comment: just to see whether the file is ok: if you execute `xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap` in cmd, does the mapping work, no error messages?

Comment: I just tried, xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap works, with no error messages!

Comment: I did a small progress: following the suggestions in  forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=294096 I have created  ~/.xprofile, and inside I have written: bash -c "sleep 5; xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap" &    On reboot, the right ctrl has worked, but only for few seconds... then it has gone back to the usual situation :-/

Comment: did you also try to add the command (maybe with full path, not $HOME variable) to Startup Applications (try to increase the delay)? And I see that you created a new question - it's better to try to solve this new problem there.

Comment: Important note for people who might want to do this on Ubuntu 20+: The default windowing system used is Wayland, in which this won't work. This solution is for X.Org windowing system. You can select the X.Org windowing system (on which this solution should work) in the login screen where you enter your password (click the small gear icon at the bottom right of the screen and select
- Ubuntu on X.Org if the two options are Ubuntu and Ubuntu on X.Org
- Ubuntu on Wayland if the two options are Ubuntu and Ubuntu on Wayland

Comment: I have "un-accepted" this answer because it solved the problem only temporary, and it required to run a script after each restart, and it even needed to re-run the script after some time.
The answer I found is definitive, stable, and with no need of scripts.