# In Linux Mint 20.2 how to execute xmodmap at startup

Tags: linux-mint, startup, xmodmap

I use Linux Mint 20.2 (with Mate desktop environment).
I need to make permanent some modifications of the keyboard mapping, as explained in the chosen answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684540/how-can-i-have-the-right-ctrl-key-behave-as-the-left-ctrl-key).
In other words, I need to execute the `xmodmap` command at each startup, and make it read its configuration file `~/.Xmodmap`.

I have followed all the suggestions in [this post](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=294096), but with no success :(

Comment: I did a small progress: following the suggestions in forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=294096 I have created ~/.xprofile, and inside I have written: bash -c "sleep 10; xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap" & On reboot, the right ctrl has worked, but only for few seconds (maybe 10 seconds?)... then it has gone back to the usual situation :-/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use a cron job for this?  Cron provides a `@reboot` parameter to schedule tasks that should run every time the computer is started up.  It is used in the following way: Open `crontab` in a terminal as so:

`crontab -e`

It will ask you which text editor you would like to use, and then at the bottom of the file you could write the following

```
# assuming your ~/.Xmodmap file is a list of keycodes that xmodmap can read
@reboot xmodmap /home/<username>/.Xmodmap
```

It is important to use full paths because the `$HOME` variable is not initialized at boot time.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work... :-/

Comment: Can you post the content of your `~/.Xmodmap` file?

Comment: Here is the content of my ~/.Xmodmap file:
keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
add control = Control_R

And if I run:  xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap  in terminal, it works!

Comment: What is it exactly you want to right control key to do?

Comment: Have you tried to add the line `if [[ -f /home<user>/.Xmodmap ]] ; then xmodmap /home/<user>/.Xmodmap ; fi` to the `/etc/X11/xinit/` file?

Comment: Or you can try putting the line `if [[ -f /home/<user>/.Xmodmap ]] ; then xmodmap /home/<user>/.Xmodmap ; fi` in your `~/.profile` as well

Comment: I have been looking around and playing with this on my system, and lots of other have had this problem.  One (roundabout) solution that I have found that works is to create a file `~/.setkeymap` with the code `xmodmap /home/<user>/.Xmodmap`, and set it to executable with `chmod 0774 .setkeymap`, then go to your startup applications and add a custom command that runs this shell script (you should probably put `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of `.setkeymap`) with a delay of 3 seconds.  It would appear that other settings change the keyboard layout, so the delay ensures that this is set last.